# How to obtain the classical Yang-Baxter equation from a related equation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, lie-algebras, integrable-systems

I have a question about the equation (1.24) in [the paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910188.pdf) about classical r-matrices.

It is said that when we put $\overline{r} = Pr$ in the equation (1.24):
$$
\overline{r}_{23}\overline{r}_{12}P_{23} + \overline{r}_{23}P_{12}\overline{r}_{23} + P_{23}\overline{r}_{12}\overline{r}_{23} = \overline{r}_{12}\overline{r}_{23}P_{12} + \overline{r}_{12}P_{23}\overline{r}_{12} + P_{12}\overline{r}_{23}\overline{r}_{12},
$$
then we obtain the classical Yang-Baxter equation (1.16)
$$
[r_{12}, r_{13}] + [r_{13}, r_{23}] + [r_{12}, r_{23}] = 0.
$$
I try to prove this statement. But I encounter some problems.

I think that we have 
$$
(Pr)_{23} = P_{23} r_{23} P_{23} = P_{32}.
$$

Therefore 
\begin{align}
& \overline{r}_{23} \overline{r}_{12} P_{23} \\
& =   P_{23} r_{23} P_{23} P_{12} r_{12} P_{12} P_{23} \\
& = r_{32} r_{21} P_{23}.
\end{align}

But I don't know how to remove $P$ in  $r_{32} r_{21} P_{23}$. How to prove the statement: when we put $\overline{r} = Pr$ in the equation (1.24), then we obtain the classical Yang-Baxter equation (1.16)? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index notation refers to the tensor factors these maps act on, i.e. $(Pr)_{23}=P_{23}r_{23}$ etc. To prove the claim, you collect all P factors on the left, where they give the total inversion permutation M on both sides of the equation. Multiplying by M from the left then gives the CYBE.